# php websocket ratchet doesn't fetch newest data from doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, doctrine, ratchet

Quite fascinating fact I just found out while messing up with WebSocket application I am now building using Symfony 4.1 and https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle (which is built upon PHP Ratchet).

I wanted to fetch the newest data periodically from the MySQL database for testing purpose using `$repository->find(2);` but it always returned the same result even though I was changing data while being subscribed to the WebSocket channel.

After quite a lot of hours of messing with the code and crying, I found out that for some reason Doctrine is caching results (or that is what I think it does).

To test my theory, I created a service that handles fetching from the database with the following code:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
 */
public function fetchNewest()
{
    $stmt = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=2');
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

and for some reason, this has worked. Can anyone explain why `find(2)` method did not result with the newest data while the raw SQL did?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct, and expected behaviour by an ORM. This is a way to lighten the load on the database.

It is well documented, but most of the time we just skip to the examples and miss it. :)

You would normally not notice this in an application, because of the PHP lifecycle. A request comes in, a response goes out, and everything, shuts down. The next request starts with a clean slate.

If you use a websocket, this never happens, PHP just runs forever (not really, but ideally), and ratchet responds to events.

(OFF: Check out PHP-PM... they have been able to reach a drastic increase in request / s because they subverted the PHP lifecycle).

Lock mode is a solution, but you could also call `$em->refresh($entity)`, which triggers a reload from db.

EDIT: docs https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map

Comment: Yep, It's kinda funny I missed this behaviour while working inside those small HTTP requests, lol. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I noticed it in a rabbitmq consumer first. Really easy to miss in a simple app. :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to figure this out myself.

Doctrine's EntityManager `find(...)` method actually caches the result inside private field called `$unitOfWork` under an entity's name and entry ID.

Every time you try to find something using `$em->find(...)` and it succeeds, the result is being stored inside `$this->unitOfWork` and if you try to fetch again the same thing it just loads from cache.

```
   // Check identity map first
    if (($entity = $unitOfWork->tryGetById($sortedId, $class->rootEntityName)) !== false) {
        if ( ! ($entity instanceof $class->name)) {
            return null;
        }

        switch (true) {
            case LockMode::OPTIMISTIC === $lockMode:
                $this->lock($entity, $lockMode, $lockVersion);
                break;

            case LockMode::NONE === $lockMode:
            case LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_READ === $lockMode:
            case LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE === $lockMode:
                $persister = $unitOfWork->getEntityPersister($class->name);
                $persister->refresh($sortedId, $entity, $lockMode);
                break;
        }

        return $entity; // Hit!
    }
```

This is the case of `"symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0"` and `"doctrine/orm": "^2.5.11"`

**Edit:**

Calling `$repository->find(2, LockMode::NONE);` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [php ratchet](http://socketo.me/) library with [pimcore](https://pimcore.com/en) and fixed the issue by just reconnecting to database on "onOpen" event of socket.

Here is the code:

```
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
{
    \Pimcore\Db::reset();
    $this->clients->attach($conn);
}
```

Hope this helps.